# Catch-all ACL attributes via CLI for Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, user-management, access-control-list, terminal

It's nice and all that one can "go crazy" [adding and subtracting ACL's from files/folders](http://www.bresink.com/osx/193281/Docs-en/ACL.html) till the cows come home...  but when [doing it from the command line](http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/acl.html), say for example..

```
$ chmod +a# 1 "admin deny delete" foo 
$ ls -lde foo 
 drwxr-xr-x + 2 apl apl 68 Jul 19 18:32 foo 
 0: group:admin allow delete 
 1: group:admin deny delete 
 2: user:tony allow delete
```

Is there an "easier" syntax that allows for "ALL" type scenarios?  Since there are [a total of 2^13 * 12 = 98,304 different access rights you can define](http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/acl.html) it would be great if you could for example state...

```
$ chmod +a "staff allow all" foo
```

But as far as I can tell, it ain't possible.  Any extended-attribute gurus out there know of any tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps, but since you can have more than one permission per ACL, you could use a couple of environment variables (e.g. in your .profile) to make it easier. Assuming your default shell is bash:

```
export FILE_ALL="read,write,append,execute,delete,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown"
export DIR_ALL="list,search,add_file,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,writesecurity,chown"
```

Then when you need to grant permissions:

```
$ chmod +a "group:admin allow $FILE_ALL" foo
```

Comment: this works well, but didn't apply `Write:Delete Subfolders + Files`, `Inheritance:Apply to Subfolders`, and `Inheritance:Apply to Enclosed Files`.  Is it just a matter of adding those "variables"?  Do you know what they would be?

Comment: The permissions are listed [in the chmod(1) man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html). I would think `Write:Delete Subfolders + Files` should be covered by `delete_child`. Try modifying through the GUI and then checking with `ls`. The `inherit_*` permissions shouldn't necessarily be part of ALL - even `chmod 777` doesn't pass on all permissions to all sub-files and folders.

Comment: i use this all the time BTW...  is there any way to combine the two?